# Access ACS chip reader from node.js

Tags: node.js, usb, libusb, smartcard-reader, node-usb

I'm trying to access the ACS chip reader (ACR1252) from node.js using node-usb library. But it seems the library is really a usage pain due no documentation. So far I got the device recognized and connect to the interfaces (just on mac, linux still not working).
When a chip is identified, the device emits `<Buffer 50 03>` and `<Buffer 50 02>` when the chip is removed.

However when sending a command to get the chip's serial number, the transfer call fails with error `undefined`.

This is my code so far:

```
import usb, { InEndpoint, OutEndpoint } from 'usb';

usb.on('attach', device => {
   device.__open();
   device.__claimInterface(0);

   device.open();

   const ifc = device.interface(0);
   ifc.claim();

   const outEndpoint: OutEndpoint = <OutEndpoint>ifc.endpoints[0];
   const inEndpoint: InEndpoint = <InEndpoint>ifc.endpoints[2];

   inEndpoint.startPoll();
   inEndpoint.on('data', (buffer: Buffer) => {
      console.warn('-- Received data: ', buffer);

      if (buffer.toString('hex') === '5003') {
         console.warn('Chip recognized!');
         outEndpoint.transfer(Buffer.from('FF CA 00 00 00', 'hex'), error => {
            console.warn('transfer error', error);
         });
      }
   });
   inEndpoint.on('error', error => {
      console.warn('error', error);
   });
});
```

Output logs:

```
-- Received data:  <Buffer 50 03>
Chip recognized!
transfer error undefined
-- Received data:  <Buffer 50 02>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to implement [CCID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCID_(protocol)) protocol to communicate with a smartcard reader (it is not that simple as sending APDU to USB endpoint).

Consider using [node-pcsclite](https://github.com/santigimeno/node-pcsclite) which provides [PC/SC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC/SC) API which is a standard way to communicate with smartcard readers -- your code will work with any smartcard reader supported by installed drivers and you won't have to implement CCID.

See [Ludovic Rousseau's blog](https://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.com/2014/09/pcsc-sample-in-javascript-nodejs.html) for an example.

Good luck with your project!

EDIT>

There is a demo CCID implementation for javascript [here](https://github.com/jbirkholz/webusbAuth).

Comment: Thanks for explanation! `node-pcsclite` works pretty good. I didn't expect that it would get that complicated :D